# List view data change According to date change

Tags: android

How to get list-view according date change from date-picker dialog in android?

For example When it is Sunday I need to show "It is holiday" otherwise List view data to be shown.

```
 edt_date.setText(getTodayDate());
            edt_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setDate(v, edt_date);
                }
            });
            System.out.print(edt_date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date today = calendar.getTime();
            String currentdate = dateFormatter1.format(today);
            String ourdate = edt_date.getText().toString();
            if (ourdate.equals(currentdate)) {
                System.out.print("Suc");
                Entry_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.entry_list_plans);
            }
            try {
                Date date = dateFormatter1.parse(ourdate);
                System.out.print(date);
                String dow = weekformat.format(date);
                System.out.print(dow);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

//Setting date from datepicker dialog

```
public void setDate(View view, final EditText edt) {

            try {
                view.requestFocus();

                final DatePickerDialog dpd;
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                // Launch Date Picker Dialog
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        mYear = year;
                        mMonth = monthOfYear;
                        mDay = dayOfMonth;
                        c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                        String tmpStr = dateFormatter1.format(c.getTime());
                        edt.setText(tmpStr);
                    }
                };
                dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                cal.clear();
                cal.set(mYear, minMonth, minDay);

                dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
                dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());

                dpd.show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("eEmp/SetDateTime", e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: not getting your point. post code here

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calender for this purpose

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

switch (day) {
 case Calendar.SUNDAY:
    // Current day is Sunday
 adapter=new CutomAdapter(items,ListShow.this);///Your List data code here
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);                 ///

 case Calendar.MONDAY:
    // Current day is Monday

 case Calendar.TUESDAY:
    // etc.
}
```

Hope this helps